# Can MS Word make "local" TOC for current header level

Tags: microsoft-word, table-of-contents

I am pretty familiar with the TOC and it's codes in Word. But for a larger project with lenghty chapters I would like to have a small summary at start of the chapter, and create a small TOC for the corresponding chapter alone.

Something like this:

```
Chapter 9
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor
    incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Tellus cras adipiscing enim eu turpis    
    egestas. Sit amet tellus cras adipiscing. 

    Chapter 9 contains   
       9.1 : About FOO      // <<< TOC for Header level 1, #9 only.
       9.2 : About BAR

   ..

9.1 About FOO
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit
..

9.2 About BAR
Sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.
```

I have not found any codes to make TOC local to header level or section.

Is the only way a combination of macro and some bookmark ?

Comment: The only thing I can find does suggest the use of bookmarks, but not macros. You might want to see if https://cybertext.wordpress.com/2011/03/04/word-adding-a-toc-for-a-section/ is at all helpful to you.

Comment: Essentially the same instructions are at https://www.bluepecantraining.com/portfolio/multiple-table-of-contents-toc-for-each-section-in-word/, and there's an embedded YouTube video of the process at https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YMAkiErPeuU

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Yes, this can be done using bookmarks.

See Word MVP Suzanne Barnhill's page on [TOC Tricks and Tips](http://wordfaqs.ssbarnhill.com/TOCTips.htm). In particular, look at the part about [a TOC for Part of a Document](http://wordfaqs.ssbarnhill.com/TOCTips.htm#PartialTOC). I strongly recommend going to that page.

*However, this forum likes things to be here rather than in links. So here is some quoted text from that page.*

> **Insert a bookmark**
>
> The general principle here is that you have to have some way to tell
> Word what part of the document you want each TOC to cover. To do that,
> you select the text you want included in the TOC (an entire chapter,
> for example) and insert a bookmark.
>
> On the Insert tab, in the Links group, click Bookmark and type in a name for your bookmark.
>
> The bookmark name can be any text you like, but it can’t contain
> spaces. So, for example, you can’t use “Chapter 1,” but you can use
> “Chapter1” or “Chapter_1.” Insert a TOC field
>
> After you have created the bookmark, you insert a TOC field at the
> desired place (at the beginning of the chapter, say).
>
> **Helpful Hint**: Give some thought to this. If you have used Heading 1 for your chapter titles, then of course you don’t want the
> chapter title included in your chapter TOC, so you will want to omit
> Level 1 from your TOC. Perhaps you’ll include just Levels 2 and 3. So
> in the Table of Contents Options dialog you’ll delete the 1 from
> beside Heading 1.
>
> But also think about formatting; unless you want the entire TOC to be indented, you don’t want to use the TOC 2 style (which by default
> has a 0.17″ indent) for Level 2. To get around this, type 1 by
> Heading 2 and 2 by Heading 3 so that the next-higher TOC style will be
> used for each heading style.
>
> **Edit the TOC field**
>
> After you have inserted the TOC (which at this point will contain many
> more entries than you want), you will have to edit it by hand. So
> press Alt+F9 to toggle the display from field results to field code.
> If you have not changed any of the default options except the levels
> as described above, the field you have inserted will look like this:
>
> { TOC \h \z \u \t "Heading 2,1,Heading 3,2" }
>
> If you want this TOC to cover your first chapter, which you have
> bookmarked as “Chapter1,” then you will type “\b Chapter1” into the
> field so it looks like this:
>
> { TOC \b Chapter1 \h \z \u \t "Heading 2,1,Heading 3,2" }
>
> Press Alt+F9 again to toggle back to the field results, then F9 to
> update the field, which should now show only the headings from Chapter
> 1.

When working with [function keys](https://www.addbalance.com/word/functionkeys.htm) like F9 some computers require that you use the Fn key with it. On a Mac, use Opt+F9 rather than Alt+F9.